# How to listen to map zoom with echarts?

Tags: angular, typescript, echarts

I'm using Echarts with Angular to display a map.

I want the map to be zoomable (done with `roaming: true` in the chart options), but also to **load a different map when the zoom is strong enough**.

*For example, if the zoom is less than 150%, I want to display a map of my country separated in regions, but if the zoom becomes more than 150%, I would like to load a finer map displaying territories inside the regions.*

Would that be possible with echarts ?

I tried to listen to the mouse scroll events, but with no success : I have access to the event only when I scroll on the echarts *component* but **not on the map**. If I do scroll on the map, the zoom is performed but I don't get any mouse scroll event.

Does anybody have a workaround to help me reach my goal ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You should listen zoom event with dataZoom event provided by library.

```
'dataZoom': function(params,charts)
{
   x1Index = params['batch'][0]['startValue']; //start index of data array
   x2Index = params['batch'][0]['endValue']; //end index of data array

   var currentOption = charts.getOption();

   //change charts option (same sintax has the original option you used to create charts
   currentOption['title'] = 'New Title'; //for example

  charts.setOption(currentOption,false); //override the current option. If the second params is true, echarts will tries to merge options but it doesn't work perfectly
}
```

Comment: does this actually work with the `roam` option? I receive no event and the docs make it seem like its only for the toolbox datazoom action

Comment: @Dumian did you find any solution? Even I am trying to achieve the same task and datazoom is not triggering.